# How could I make the hilt guard look like one whole piece as opposed to three pieces put together?

Tags: modeling

I used two cylinders for the hilt guards but I pretty much just traces the rest of the hilt by extruding a vertex around the reference image (tracing it).

Reference:

[image: Reference image]

My model:
[image: Full view]

[image: Close up]

[image: Close up 2]

I only used the solidify modifier, but as expected, it didn't help much. I'm still very new to Blender so I'm sure there is something out there I haven't found yet.

I'd also appreciate it if you have any tutorials you'd like to suggest for problems like. (It's not an easily youtubable title to find a solution for)

Edit:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure where the Solidify is useful. As for the question, if you want to make it of one piece, create a face within a face (like for example with an inset operation) that has the shape of the extrusion to come? Maybe show what part in particular you're struggle with?

Comment: @moonboots what modifies should I be applying here? or which would you suggest I mess around with for this model?

Comment: use a Mirror modifier as your sword is symmetrical, and a Subdivision Surface to make the shape rounder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you want to have a cylinder extruded from a cuboid, but you want to make it as one piece, not several:

[image]

In that case add a bit of topology to your cuboid with some new loopcuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>):

[image]

Inset the 4 top faces, then right click *> LoopTools > Circle* (you need to activate the LoopTools addon of course):

[image]

Then extrude, etc:

[image]

For the shape you highlight, here are the steps:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Also, what about the corners from the larger piece? Would you just scale the edges down to look like it's transitioning into that shape? (if that makes sense)

Comment: Please see my edit